# How to prove $\sin(x-a) + \sin(x+a) = 2\sin(x)\cos(a)$?

Tags: trigonometry

Haven't been able to find a solution on how to show this online ?

Any help so I can understand this would be appreciated.

Comment: This is a corollary of the addition formula

Comment: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ProsthaphaeresisFormulas.html  and   http://mathworld.wolfram.com/WernerFormulas.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using $\sin(x+y) = \sin(x)\cos(y) + \cos(x)\sin(y)$ as suggested

This means that:

$\sin(x+a) = \sin(x)\cos(a) + \cos(x)\sin(a)$,

$\sin(x-a) = \sin(x)\cos(-a) + \cos(x)\sin(-a) = \sin(x)\cos(a) - \cos(x)\sin(-a)$,

since $\cos(-x)=\cos(x)$ and $\sin(-x)=-\sin(x)$

Adding $\sin(x-a)$ and $\sin(x+a)$ together gives,

$\sin(x+a)$ + $\sin(x-a)$ = $2\sin(x)\cos(a)$

Answer (score 5):

HINT

$\sin{(x+y)}=\sin{x}\cos{y}+\cos{x}\sin{y}$